# Stage vs Prod: Importing Spreadsheet Data into Production Deployment

Tags: google-app-maker

For the most part I'm ok with there being separate stage and prod databases, but one of my databases is just a lookup table. To encode it I hard imported data from a spreadsheet using IMPORT DATA FROM SHEET.

Is there any way to do the same with my live/production app?

Comment: When you go to a datasource and select to import data from sheet, your top dropdown is where you select the deployment that you want to import the data into.

Comment: AWesome thanks markus